# Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error, unexpected-token, uncaught-reference-error

I have encountered a Syntax error in my javascript code. I'm getting a message of 'Unexpected token else' error.
I hope someone can help me with this. Here is my code:

```
function doRed() {
  for (var pixel of img.values()){
    var avg = (pixel.getRed()+pixel.setGreen()+pixel.getBlue())/3;
    if ( avg() < 128) {
    pixel.setRed(2*avg);
    pixel.setGreen(0);
    pixel.setBlue(0);
  }
    }
  else {
    pixel.setRed(255);
    pixel.setGreen(2*avg - 255);
    pixel.setBlue(2*avg - 255);
  }
  var imgcanvas = document.getElementById("can");
  img.drawTo(imgcanvas);
}
```

Comment: The closing `}` of your `for` loop is in the wrong place

Comment: my bad, I missplaced the "}" over the else statement. This code is for a button that applies a red filter to an image. Still, when I press the button there is no change on the image

Comment: you put the `else` on the `for` loop

Comment: You have `for ( ... ) { ... } else { ... }` which is wrong. `else` is not allowed after `for`. If you indent your code consistently and properly, you'll see it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else`-statement is in the wrong position, following the `for`-loop instead of the `if`-statement.

You probably meant to write it like this:

```
function doRed() {
  for (var pixel of img.values()) {
    var avg = (pixel.getRed()+pixel.setGreen()+pixel.getBlue())/3;
    if (avg() < 128) {
      pixel.setRed(2*avg);
      pixel.setGreen(0);
      pixel.setBlue(0);
    }
    else {
      pixel.setRed(255);
      pixel.setGreen(2*avg - 255);
      pixel.setBlue(2*avg - 255);
    }
  }

  var imgcanvas = document.getElementById("can");
  img.drawTo(imgcanvas);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Still the function of my code itself isn´t doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @AlexisHarrison Yes, but that's [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which needs additional details.

Comment: @AlexisHarrison That's a different matter. :) If this answers the question as stated, please mark the answer as accepted, and create a new question if you need further help with something else.

Comment: I already figured it out guys, thank you so much for your help!